# What happens when git push origin HEAD:refs/for/branch

Tags: git, gerrit, git-push

I have been using this command for a while for pushing my code in Gerrit..

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/branch
```

However, recently I am working on an infrastructure which doesn't have a Gerrit pipeline. I could do a push, but I wasn't able to see the branch on  git. When I run:

```
git push origin branch
```

it can be seen on git. I am trying this on a new branch, which I created locally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command git push works like the following:

```
git push REPOSITORY SOURCE_REFSPEC:DESTINATION_REFSPEC
```

With Gerrit, when you use:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/branch
```

You're asking Git to:

- REPOSITORY=origin

Push to the origin repository (by default, the repository you have cloned from)

- SOURCE_REFSPEC=HEAD

Push the current commit of your working tree

- DESTINATION_REFSPEC=refs/for/branch

Push the commit to "branch" to be reviewed on Gerrit. The "refs/for/" prefix is a "magical" branch which "instruct" Gerrit that a Code Review must be created. See more info about this [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-gerrit-walkthrough.html#_creating_the_review).

The "refs/for/" prefix only makes sense if you're working with Gerrit.

Finally, if you're not working with Gerrit and execute "git push origin branch" you're pushing your current commit to the "branch" branch on "origin" repository.

Comment: aahhh.. Makes a lot more sense now.. So ref/for/branch is used a reference by gerrit for which branch the code has to be pushed to, rather than pushing/creating the branch straight ahead. Where as doing so in GIT doesn't make any sense (so as to me right now.)....

Comment: Thanks a lot  mate for your answer

Comment: Great... could you accept the answer clicking on the check sign?